# Tracking Dynamic Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, deliverability, email-tracking

I've created a SenderProfile with dynamics variables as `%%from_name%%` and `%%from_email%%`.

Now, the customer needs to know how many emails was send by sender individually. Is there a way to obtain this report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting up a SendLog:

> The Send Log Data Extension is an ongoing record accessible to users
>   within Marketing Cloud that stores Send-Time data specified by the
>   Admin User, including subscriber specific Attribute data or Unique
>   Use-Case Data Extension row data.   This ongoing record provides
>   access to data that isn't readily accessible via standard Tracking
>   Data or Reports within Marketing Cloud

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333925&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1

In the SendLog Data Extension, you would need to add two additional columns called `from_name` and `from_email`.

Depending how you send emails, you will need to make sure that the Send Logging flag is checked for all email sends(Email Studio, Journey Builder, Triggered Sends).

It will start logging values in the two additional columns whenever you use `%%from_name%%` and `%%from_email%%` in an email send.